# Issue in Change set Upload

Tags: deployment

We cannot able to move the deployment from Sandbox (dev) to Sandbox (dev2) via change set, as we get an error while uploading the changeset.
Error Number - 245827274.

While checked found in Success community and documentation, found that this is because of incompatibility of the updates in both the sandboxes.
Source Org :Sandbox(dev) - Summer 2018
Destination Org :Sanbox (dev2) - Spring 2018

Please help to fix this issue as earliest as possible.

Thank you,
Gayathri S

Comment: Did you create a ticket with salesforce support?

Comment: Yes, I have created It

Comment: I would like to suggest to go through change set components, and check the API version of all components to see if they are newer than target instance's API version, if not might need to set them to earlier version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that you have added the documents which are used in any custom app.
If so please add the document in changeset and try again.

Comment: I have checked this, Its working fine.
Thank you for the response